# adding li to ul using jquery works just one time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page with a link in it , when pressing the link I want to add new LI to UL using jQuery, I created my jQuery function and it works just one time, I mean, jQuery function works for just on click

## jquery

```
$("#addRelation").ready(function (){
    $("#addRelation a").css("padding","6px");
    $("#addRelation .araNew").bind('click',function(){
        $("#addRelation .araNew").hide();
        $("#addRelation ul li:last").append('<li> \n\
<p>\n\
      <label>Source</label>\n\
      <select name="source[]" id="source">\n\
             <option>select source</option>\n\
      </select>\n\
</p>\n\
<p>\n\
      <label>Destination</label>\n\
      <select name="destination[]" id="destination">\n\
              <option>select destination</option>\n\
      </select>\n\
</p>\n\
 <p>\n\
       <a href="#" class="araNew">new</a> \n\
       <a href="#" class="araDel">delete</a> \n\
</p>\n\
</li>');
    });
```

## html

```
<div class="container" id="addRelation">
    <ul class="containerUL">
        <li class="containerLI">
            <label>Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="relationName" class="longInput1"/>
            <div id="arSuggestions"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Related Concepts</label>
            <p>
                <label>Source</label>
                <select name="source[]" id="source">
                    <option>select source</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <label>Destination</label>
                <select name="destination[]" id="destination">
                    <option>select destination</option>
                </select>
            </p>
            <p>
                <a href="#" class="araNew">new</a>
                <a href="" class="araDel">delete</a>
            </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and also any suggestions for adding li to ul different from my function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add your append code inside [$.on](http://api.jquery.com/on) syntax like this

```
$("#addRelation").on('click','.araNew',function(){
 // add li code

});
```

Check the working [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/4pVPx/)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are adding a new `a` element to the DOM, but the event handler is bound to the old one. You can use event delegation (with the jQuery [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method, or [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) if you're using a version below 1.7) to capture the click event higher up the DOM tree:

```
$("#addRelation").on("click", ".araNew", function() {
    //Do stuff...
});
```

This will capture the click event when it reaches the ancestor `div` element. It will check to see if the event target matches `.araNew`, and if it does it will execute the event handler. This way, the handler will execute no matter which element matching `.araNew` you click.

Alternatively, you could simply move the "new" and "delete" links outside of the `ul`, instead of creating new ones each time.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're dynamically inserting the element(s) at a later time. Use `.on` to attach the click event handler, this will ensure the event handler is called for dynamically inserted elements as well.

```
$("#addRelation").on('click', '.araNew', function(){
    // code here        
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're hiding the old `araNew` and adding a new one without binding the click to it.

Comment: but on my jquery i make the event on the class not on the tag A

Comment: Yes, but it binds to all nodes with the class *at the time* you issue the `bind()`. Anything created after that is not bound.